# How do I use this state within React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fairly new to React and I have the following code

```
   import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'


function Box(props) {
  return (<button className="cell" onClick={() => props.handleClick(props.index)}>{props.children}</button>); 
}
function PlayGrid(props){
  
  //console.log("props in playgrid: " ,props);

  return (
    <div className="grid" id="playGrid">
        {props.history.squares.map( (cell, index) => {
          //console.log("cell: ", cell);
          return (<Box index={index} handleClick={props.squareClick} key={index} className="cell">{cell}</Box>);
        })}
    </div>
    );
}

function Game() {
  const [history, setHistory] = useState([{squares: Array(9).fill(null)}]);
  const [turnCount, setTurnCount] = useState("X");
  const [winner, setWinner] = useState(null);

  const moves = history.map((object, index) => {
    const description = index === 0 ? "Go to start" :  "Go to move " + (index);
    return(<li>
      <button onClick = {() => jumpTo(index + 1)}>{description}</button>
      </li>);
  }); //we will use a map feature that maps each move to a button.
  
  function didSomeoneWin(squares){
    console.log("history: ", history, " squares: ", squares);
    const lines = [
      [0,1,2],
      [3,4,5],
      [6,7,8],
      [0,3,6],
      [1,4,7],
      [2,5,8],
      [0,4,8],
      [6,4,2],
    ];
    lines.forEach((line) => {
      const [a,b,c] = line;
      if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[b] === squares[c]){
        console.log("SOMEONE WON!");
        setWinner(squares[a]); // return the winner: X or O
        console.log("Squares[a]: ", squares[a], "WINNER IS NOW: ", winner);
      }
      else {
        setWinner(null);
      }
    })
  }

  function squareClick(i){
    if (winner !== "X" && winner !== "O"){
      //TODO: Fix this function by resolving the async issues. posted on SO.
      console.log("winner: ", winner);
      setTurnCount(history.length % 2 === 0 ? "X" : "O");   
      const current = history[history.length - 1];
      const squares = current.squares.slice();
      if (squares[i]){
        return;
      }
      squares[i] = turnCount;
      console.log(i);
      console.log("history before: ", history[history.length - 1]);
      setHistory(history.concat([{ squares: squares }]));
      console.log("history after: ", history[history.length - 1]);
      didSomeoneWin(squares);
    }
  }

  function jumpTo(i) {
    const newHistory = history.slice(0, i);
    setHistory(newHistory);
    didSomeoneWin();
  }

  return (
  <div className="row">
    <div className="column">
      <div>Current Turn: {turnCount}</div>
      <ol>{moves}</ol>
    </div>
    <div className="column">
      <PlayGrid squareClick={squareClick} history={history[history.length - 1]}/>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
}

function App(){
  return(<Game/>);
}

export default App;
```

I am having an issue with my squareClick(i) method not getting the winner from the state presumably because of some kind of async issue with the state. How can I resolve this issue in my code?

Additional text so my posting can get posted: Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Comment: Where is `squareClick` being called from? Can you include your render method?

Comment: Sorry, I just added the full code. It is being called from my square functional component?

Comment: Your call to `didSomeoneWin` in `jumpTo` isn't passing the variable `i`

Comment: Thank you. I went ahead and fixed that. However, winner is still null when squareClick(i) was called.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wondering why this line isn't working:

```js
console.log("Squares[a]: ", squares[a], "WINNER IS NOW: ", winner);
```

It's because when this line executes, the `winner` state has not been set yet so it's still null. Instead of console logging here, you should look at what you actually want to do with the state, and combine that with `useEffect`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(winner);
}, [winner]}
```

The above snippet means the call back will run when the value of `winner` changes.

You can also add some html output to the return statement to see that the value is being updated:

```js
return (
  <span>Winner: {winner}</span>
  ...
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, the central problem is that "winner" is not being set.

Comment: It is being set, see this code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-tree-x8j3s, you just *think* it's not being set because you are console logging before the react state is updated.